# How can I get post into my homepage?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to get post into my wordpress homepage, I tried to search lot from google but I am not geting any proper solutions, So if any one have idea please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my tried code so far :

```
<?php
                    $args = array(
                    'cat' => '5',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 8,
                    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
                    );
                    query_posts($args);
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div id="part-event">
                        <div id="entry-thumbnail">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                        </div>
                        <div id="event-dess">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <p>
                            <?php 
                            $content = get_the_content();
                            $content = strip_tags($content);
                            echo substr($content,0,300)." . . . ";
                            ?>
                            </p>
                            <div id="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="line-bottom"></div>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;

                    ?>
                </div>
                <div id="page-gina">
                    <?php 
                    //wp_pagenavi();
                    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean HTTP POST? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Two Ways is possible,

i)Create a custom template.

ii)In your page.php check condition.

Ex:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){
                        echo "This Home";//Here Your code
     }
?>
```